# Thunderbird 68 (64 bit) - can't save attachment

Tags: thunderbird, attachments

I use Thunderbird 68 (64 bit) on Windows 10 64 bit with 6 IMAP mailboxes and one GMail mailbox. With one of the 6 IMAP mailbox there is the following problem: if the mailbox gets a mail with an attachment, I can't access the attachment, the "Download" buutton is gray, "unknown size" is shown, and on double click on the attachment nothing happens. If the same mail arrives into an other mailbox, there is no problem with the attachments. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't see a Download button anywhere in Thunderbird 68. Are you sure this isn't some non-functional add-on?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when upgrade to v68. I try to roll back to v60.9, and the attachment save function works again. It is probably a bug since v68 is too new and untested. You can download the old version here: https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/60.9.0/win64/en-US/
I will probably wait for v69 and see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Please try 68.1.1, just out a few hours ago.  Make sure to download the same "bit" version, 32 or 64, as you are currently running.

Comment: Thank yout! Upgrading to 68.1.1 (64 bit version) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in Thunderbird 68 (64 bit), witch causes, if a letter has an attachment, the "Save" button doesn't works and the size of the attachment is 'unknown'. Upgrading to Thunderbird 68.1.1 solves the problem.